# How should I create a Clang NamedDecl instance?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

As a learning exercise, I am trying to build a C++ AST in code using the Clang classes directly.

The `NamedDecl` constructor is `protected`.

How can I create a `NamedDecl` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NamedDecl` is used by Clang as a base class for more specific decls that are named (e.g. `ValueDecl`, `TypeDecl`, ...) which are still mostly base classes for more specific Decl kinds. Thus Clang doesn't want you to create a NamedDecl directly and urges you to create something more specific.

If for example the decl you want to create an object for represents a class you should create a `RecordDecl` or a `XCCRecordDecl`.

Of course you can circumvent this mechanism by deriving from `clang::NamedDecl` and making the constructor of the derived class public.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. For future readers, I found clang::IntegerLiteral a good class to start with.